# Random number: 0 or 1

Tags: c#, random

Am I looking too far to see something as simple as pick a number: 0 or 1?

```
        Random rand = new Random();

        if (rand.NextDouble() == 0)
        {
            lnkEvents.CssClass = "selected";
        }
        else
        {
            lnkNews.CssClass = "selected";
        }
```

Comment: All the solutions below, have you create a new Random object.  That is fine unless you create a bunch of them very quickly.  If you do, then there is a good chance they will all have the same random seed, and you will get the same result over and over.  To avoid the issue, create a Random somewhere in your program and pass it around.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
Random rand = new Random();

if (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0)
    lnkEvents.CssClass = "selected";
else
    lnkNews.CssClass = "selected";
```

[Random.Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) picks a random integer between the lower bound (inclusive) and the upper bound (exclusive).

Comment: This is the one I would go for.

Comment: Note: Random rand = new Random(); should, ideally, be stuck somewhere else, not right above the call to rand.Next.  Ideally, it should be initialized once.

Comment: @Brian Random isn't thread safe so your suggestion would require synchronization if used in concurrently.

Comment: @Tom: A valid point.  The use of `CssClass` implies that this is very likely.  Happily, Jon Skeet [wrote a wrapper](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness/) that resolves this problem.

Answer (score 30):

If you want 50/50 probability, I suggest:

```
Random rand = new Random();

if (rand.NextDouble() >= 0.5)
    lnkEvents.CssClass = "selected";
else
    lnkNews.CssClass = "selected";
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like what you're wanting to do (choose between two values) is more clearly expressed by using the [`Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.next.aspx) method, instead of the [`NextDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx) method.

```
const int ExclusiveUpperBound = 2;
if (new Random().Next(ExclusiveUpperBound) == 0)
```

The value produced is "greater than or equal to zero, and less than" `ExclusiveUpperBound`.

Answer (score 2):

`Random.NextDouble()` will select any double number from 0 but less than 1.0. Most of these numbers are not zero, so your distribution will not be as even as you expect.

Comment: "not be as even as you expect" is understatement of the year. Virtually all generated results would be 1.

Comment: For the record: I've never seen a zero being returned by a PRNG. And I've tested them a lot a few months ago :-)

Answer (score 0):

If not in a tight loop you could use

```
(DateTime.Now.Millisecond % 2) - double DateTime.Now.Millisecond % (double) 10) / 10
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach could be:

```
Random random = new Random();
bool result = random.Next(0, 2) != 0;
```

Then use result for your logic.